# Update Statement using two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to set the cust in the installed products table to be the ID in the Customers table, have tried a few statements with no luck; just need pointing in the right direction.

Here is what I have:

```
UPDATE InstalledProducts
    SET InstalledProducts.cust = Customers.ID
FROM InstalledProducts, Customers
WHERE InstalledProducts.SiteName = Customers.SiteName
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would write this:

```
UPDATE InstalledProducts ip
    SET cust = 
(SELECT ID FROM Customers
WHERE ip.SiteName = SiteName)
```

Answer (score 1):

The update statement with JOIN should be as

```
update 
InstalledProducts ip
join Customers c on c.SiteName = ip.SiteName
set ip.cust = c.ID
```